# How to use conditional formatting to color based on an another sheets answer

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a table that has an X and Y columns with Zs randomly populated within it. On a seperate sheet it shows that Z1,Z2, etc etc passed or failed. I want it to match then color the table based off this seperate sheet. So for example if Z1 passed highlight it green or Z2 failed then highlight it red. Then if both passed in the row highlight it all green, highlight red if all failed, or yellow if one failed and other passed. The image is an example of how I would like it set up.[image: Example table with X and Y columns][image: Pass/Fail of Zs]

I've tried messing with condtional formatting by using the if/and, match,vlookup, and match/index functions. So far nothing has actually done it currently or accurately. I believe this is something that will need the VBA editor. I have very little experience with it so any help and details on how/why it was used would be greatly appericated.

Comment: `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$B,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!$A:$A,0))="Passed",FALSE)` this does the trick. Sheet2 is the sheet from your 2nd image, and this is the conditional formatting formula applied to the entire sheet1(1st image)

Comment: Thank you that worked to highlight sheet 1, but any idea on how to color A column based on colors in the table?